# TextFieldShouldReturn messes up a selector

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a single `UITextField` called `titleTextField` and a `UIBarButtonItem` called `save` 
I've set the `titleTextField .delegate = self` in `viewDidload()`

Now, when I have the following code and tap on `Return` key, the keyboard is being dismissed but when I try to tap on `save` button absolutely nothing happens. I put a breakpoint on the button, it's not being called.

I put a breakpoint on the `textFieldShouldReturn` and it's being called as expected. If I comment out the `textFieldShouldReturn` code, the button is working. I'm not sure what exactly is happening.

```
extension CreateN : UITextFieldDelegate {

func handleTextFields() {
    titleTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
}

@objc func textFieldDidChange() {
    guard let title = titleTextField.text, !title.isEmpty
        else {
            saveButton.isEnabled = false
            return
    }
    saveButton.isEnabled = true
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    titleTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
}

class CreateN: UIViewController { 
    let saveButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveTapped))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    titleTextField.delegate = self
    setNavSaveButton()
    handleTextFields()
    }

 func setNavSaveButton() {
    saveButton.isEnabled = false
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = saveButton
}


    @objc func saveTapped() {
        print("Tap")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was very interesting issue and to resolve that you need to replace

```
let saveButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveTapped))
```

with

```
var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!
```

and into your `viewDidLoad` method add

```
saveButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveTapped))
```

and final code for `viewDidLoad` will be:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    saveButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveTapped))
    titleTextField.delegate = self
    setNavSaveButton()
    handleTextFields()
}
```

And it will work totally fine.

Comment: You should use `var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!`, not `var saveButton = UIBarButtonItem()`. No need to create and throw away an empty instance.

Comment: Updated. Thanks.